# O que fazer com títulos fora de contexto?

Tags: debate

O que deveriamos fazer com uma pergunta que diz no título "Evento não funciona", e, quando vamos olhar, o conteúdo da pergunta não tem nada a ver com o "Evento", por exemplo?

Deveriamos editar esses títulos (ou seja, tentar criar um título baseado no corpo da pergunta)?

Pedir para o usuário alterar? Ou recomendar o fechamento como "Não está claro"?

Comment: Edite. *Edite*. **Edite**. ***Edite***.

Comment: Se vc entendeu a ideia da pergunta, altere o título para algo mais adequado, se apenas suspeita faça um comentário para confirmar isso. Relacionado: [Editar título cujo contexto e resolução não condizem](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4152/91) e [Edição de título para facilitar as buscas](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3827/91)

Comment: Ou peça para outra pessoa fazer, assim você está coerente com quem pede para você fazer :)

Comment: @rray: seu comentário já é uma resposta ou até mesmo um voto para fechar como duplicado, que é o que acredito ser e acabo de votar ;)

Comment: Veja um [exemplo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/2040/revisions) de edições que pegaram o objetivo da pergunta, veja o histórico de edições.